# How do I make sure a Wi-Fi driver (installed as kernel object) still runs after a kernel upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, wifi-driver

I have installed a driver as *.ko (built it from source), and placed it in `/etc/modules`

After rebooting, the driver failed to load, and I noticed that I'm actually running a new kernel (probably changed during the last update from the software center).

I somehow get a feeling that there is a way to make the driver get installed each time the kernel updates without me doing it manually.

So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the source to the driver (something you do not explicitly state in your post), then you will need to recompile it. There is an application that may take care of this for you, which is called **dkms** for `Dynamic Kernel Module Support`.

Basically what you need to do is to create a `dkms.conf` file in the directory created by the un'tarring of the package, then place these lines in the `dkms.conf` file:

```
  PACKAGE_NAME=r8168
  PACKAGE_VERSION=8.032.00
  MAKE[0]="'make'"
  BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]=r8168
  BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="./"
  DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/updates/dkms"
  AUTOINSTALL="YES"
```

The directories are identified by their relative paths; the origin of that relative path is the directory where the `dkms.conf` file is located. Remember to check that the make commands are correct, you will have to check them against the usual README.txt file included in every package.

Now, always from this directory, we copy everything to its destination directory:

```
  sudo cp -R . /usr/src/r8168-8.032.00/
```

Lastly, you tell `dkms` to do its thing:

```
  dkms add -m r8168 -v 8.032.00
  dkms build -m r8168 -v 8.032.00
  dkms install -m r8168 -v 8.032.00
```

and you are done.

Edit:

sorry, I forgot you need to install the kernel headers, and make/config/gcc,... which in Debian-family distros (Debian,Ubuntu,Mint...aptosid...) can be downloaded by means of:

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Other distros have equivalent commands.

Comment: Yes I have the source for the driver. My driver has the Makefile in its root folder, and doesn't have any `src` folder. Also, when installing it i just ran `make && make install` without specifying the `KERNELDIR` variable, so should i just run `make && make install` in the `MAKE` variable? where to point the `BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION`?

Comment: @ordahan I have edited my answer to reflect your comment. As for the BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION, that should be the directory where the .ko file is left. In the post above, I assumed it is left in the directory from which you are issuing your commands. You will have to check that this is the case, because it depends on your makefile.

Comment: I get this error when trying to add to `dkms`: `dkms.conf: Error! No 'DEST_MODULE_LOCATION' directive specified for record #0.
dkms.conf: Error! Directive 'DEST_MODULE_LOCATION' does not begin with
'/kernel', '/updates', or '/extra' in record #0.
Error! Bad conf file.
`

Comment: @ordahan I have given, in the answer, an example of a working dkms.conf. This is one I use. Let me know.

Comment: yeah thx, i just needed to set the `DEST_MODULE_LOCATION`